# In Excel, what are good ways to handle blanks in input data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a range of some raw input data in an Excel sheet. For illustration purposes, let's say it's in Sheet1!A1:E10. And suppose I want to have that be copied into another sheet -- Sheet2!A1:E10, say. And assume I want it done using formulae, rather than manually copy/pasting. So a simple approach would be to have, in cell Sheet2!A1, the following formula:

`=Sheet1!A1:E10`

But what if there are blank cells in the input range. In that case, the above will place zeros into the corresponding cells in the target range. One way around that is:

`=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1:E10),"",Sheet1!A1:E10)`

which is fine provided I'm OK with that null string representing where the blanks were. At the moment, my preferre approach is similar, but is slightly better in terms of compatibility with Google Sheets, and it is:

`= IF(LEN(Sheet1!A1:E10)=0,"",Sheet1!A1:E10)`

But overall, it still feels clumsy and a bit of a pain to have to do that check. Is there a neater, more succinct way?

Comment: what sort of "succinct" way you are in search for?

Comment: Well I was hoping maybe there was an option somewhere, called something like "Propagate Blanks" :-) If that existed then the first formula above would be fine. As it is, more than double the number of characters is needed to handle what I'd have thought is a phenomenally common matter. So anything that shortens and simplifies will be an improvement.

Comment: Do any of the solutions here work: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/

Comment: Hi @tkp, since your formula never produces zero in place of blank cells and creates an identical data set,, in this case what exactly you are looking for ? Please [edit] your post & be specific about your exact need, and avoid vote to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365 and data *Sheet1* like:

[image]

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:A10,LEN(Sheet1!A1:A10))
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I love the new dynamic array funtions, but it'snot what I need here. FILTER() *removes* blanks. The point here is that a cell being blank carries a meaning and I want to preserve it. The blank cells are not text; they're not numbers greater than zero, or less than zero, or zero. They're blank. As it stands, I'm OK to let a null string act in place of a blank, and so if Excel would copy blanks as null strings, it'd be fine. But it doesn't. It copies blanks as zeros. Unless someone knows otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Since formula used by you creates identical column and never produces zero for blank cells, you need an array (CSE) formula to works smartly to get set of data by skipping blanks :*

[image]

- Formula in cell `C2`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$14<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$14)),ROWS($A2:$A$2))-1),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: The op wants to simplify the 'formula' that already does its job. The one formula you've provided only adds to the complexity.

Comment: @Sanu_012, What I and Gary's Student suggested are the correct method, and the formula used by OP does nothing except copies the same data along with blanks ,, and skip blank is the issue  !!

Comment: OP wants to propagate blanks, that means he wants to keep the cells blank (and not zero) while copying to another sheet using formulas. Also, he already found a way to do that using the 2nd formula he gave, but it feels too lengthy for him. So, he just wants a way to make it precise. It's not as complicated as it sounds. But above all, he don't want to remove blanks.

Comment: @Sanu_012,, OP formula never produces ZERO between or in place of BLANKs,,, whether handling Text/ Number or even Date ,, just check ,, !!

Comment: Yes, his formula never produces zero in place of blanks and that's exactly what he wants. But, he just want a precise way to achieve the same exact thing - like a more precise version of that formula :|

Comment: @Sanu_012, nothing should replace since task is just make identical column,, that's is the reason we have had suggested OP to do in that way,,, instead of just duplicating ,,, a smart method,, sometimes due to lack of experience this happens!

Comment: Oh for god's sake, you are misunderstanding, sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108024/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-sanu-012).